# Changing the name attribute in react actually stops selecting the values from dropdown

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a developed project and new to React. I have copied a Dropdown from a previously implemented one.

```
 {/* Previously Implemented Code */}
 <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell>Planned Project Type</Table.Cell>
 </Table.Row>

  <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell ><PtInputConditionTab whichInput="firsttb" inputType="hwy" name="PlannedProjType" disabled value={typeOptions[this.state.PlannedProjType > 4 ? 0 : this.state.PlannedProjType].label}
      onChange={this.onInputChange} />
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell ><PtSelect options={typeOptions.slice(0,5)}
                    onChange={this.onChangeDropdown} disabled={this.props.disabled} defaultVal={this.state.PlannedProjTypeOver} name="PlannedProjTypeOver" /></Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  {/* Previously Implemented Code Ends */}

  {/* Previously implemented code copied */}
   <Table.Row>
    <Table.Cell>Planned Project Type</Table.Cell>
 </Table.Row>

  <Table.Row>
      <Table.Cell ><PtInputConditionTab whichInput="firsttb" inputType="hwy" name="PlannedProjType" disabled value={typeOptions[this.state.PlannedProjType > 4 ? 0 : this.state.PlannedProjType].label}
      onChange={this.onInputChange} />
      </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell ><PtSelect options={typeOptions.slice(0,5)}
                    onChange={this.onChangeDropdown} disabled={this.props.disabled} defaultVal={this.state.PlannedProjTypeOver} name="PlannedProjectSurfaceTypeOver" /></Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  {/* Previously Implemented Copied Code Ends */}
```

When I change the name attribute in the second section of PtSelect tag the dropdown doesnt show the selected value. It always shows the first value of the dropdown even after clicking on other values inside the dropdown. Just to let you know when I do console.log() for the value selected it is selecting those options its just that not displaying them which one is selected.
Just to make sure you understood it properly, I am trying to change the name in the section which is inside the comment line "Previously implemented code copied"

Comment: I got it fixed. Its just the defaultVal attribute parameter which I passed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. Its just the defaultVal attribute parameter which I passed incorrectly.